# Annotated plot over heatmap with seaborn and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I cannot overlay plot over the heatmap (heatmap should be seaborn plotted).

Here is my small example of data

```
mat = [
    [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [3,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [6,2,8,2,1,0,0,4,2],
    [3,1,2,3,1,2,4,1,4],
    [3,1,9,4,1,3,2,1,5],
]

iters = [1, 2, 8, 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, 1024] # iterations for x-axis
names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # 5 clusters 
maxim = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1] # maximum cluster at iter 
conc = ["dog", "spoon", "table", "bike", "hat", "hat", "porch", "sweater", "bird"] # maximum concept in cluster  for annotation
```

and plotting

```
def plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(iter_scores, iters, cluster_names, maximum_cluster, max_concepts):
    import seaborn as sns
    ax = sns.heatmap(iter_scores, cmap="gist_yarg")
    plt.xticks(range(len(iters)), iters, rotation=90);
    plt.yticks(range(len(cluster_names)), cluster_names, rotation=0);
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), size=7)

    
    plt.plot(iters, maximum_cluster, marker='o', )
    #annotate markers
    prev_cl = None
    for it, ci, cl in zip(iters, maximum_cluster, max_concepts):
        if prev_cl is None or prev_cl != cl:    
            plt.annotate(cl, (it, ci), rotation=40, size=12)
            prev_cl = cl
    plt.show()
    
plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(mat, iters, names, maxim, conc)
```

But I have errors like

```
ValueError: Image size of 76240x871 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

Can someone help me to improve my code so it works and does its job (I bet there are few issues)?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that we annotated the heat map with location information that is beyond the data range of the heat map. We have created a new x-axis value and changed the format to annotate based on it. Values of `iters` greater than or equal to 8 are beyond the graph range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mat = [
    [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [3,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [6,2,8,2,1,0,0,4,2],
    [3,1,2,3,1,2,4,1,4],
    [3,1,9,4,1,3,2,1,5],
]

iters = [1, 2, 8, 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, 1024] # iterations for x-axis
names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # 5 clusters 
maxim = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1] # maximum cluster at iter 
conc = ["dog", "spoon", "table", "bike", "hat", "hat", "porch", "sweater", "bird"] # maximum concept in cluster  for annotation
maxlen = np.arange(1,10)

def plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(iter_scores, iters, cluster_names, maximum_cluster, max_concepts, maxl):
    import seaborn as sns
    ax = sns.heatmap(iter_scores, cmap="gist_yarg")
    plt.xticks(range(len(iters)), iters, rotation=90);
    plt.yticks(range(len(cluster_names)), cluster_names, rotation=0);
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), size=7)

    
    plt.plot(iters, maximum_cluster, marker='o')
#     #annotate markers
    prev_cl = None
    for it, ci, cl, ma in zip(iters, maximum_cluster, max_concepts, maxl):
        if prev_cl is None or prev_cl != cl:    
            plt.annotate(cl, (ma, ci), rotation=40, size=12, xycoords='data')
            prev_cl = cl
    plt.show()
    
plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(mat, iters, names, maxim, conc, maxlen)
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot accept your answer because table, bike, hat and bird are not connected by a plot and even bird flies out of the chart. It is clearly not a proper chart. But anyway, I have solved the problem

Comment: It is up to you whether you accept it or not. You have pointed out a different challenge than the solution to the question, but isn't your code the cause?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. The key is to use `range(len(iters))` for annotation and plotting instead of `iters`.

```
#test
mat = [
    [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [3,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,5],
    [6,2,8,2,1,0,0,4,2],
    [3,1,2,3,1,2,4,1,4],
    [3,1,9,4,1,3,2,1,5],
]

iters = [1, 2, 8, 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, 1024] # iterations for x-axis
names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # 5 clusters 
maxim = [1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1] # maximum cluster at iter 
conc = ["dog", "spoon", "table", "bike", "hat", "hat", "porch", "sweater", "bird"] # maximum concept in cluster  for annotation

def plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(iter_scores, iters, cluster_names, maximum_cluster, max_concepts):
    import seaborn as sns
    ax = sns.heatmap(iter_scores, cmap="gist_yarg")
    plt.xticks(range(len(iters)), iters, rotation=90);
    plt.yticks(range(len(cluster_names)), cluster_names, rotation=0);
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), size=7)

    plt.plot(range(len(iters)), maximum_cluster, marker='o')
    #annotate markers
    prev_cl = None
    for it, ci, cl in zip(range(len(iters)), maximum_cluster, max_concepts):
        if prev_cl is None or prev_cl != cl:    
            plt.annotate(cl, (it, ci), rotation=40, size=12, xycoords='data')
            prev_cl = cl
    plt.show()
    
plot_cluster_heatmap_over_iters(mat, iters, names, maxim, conc)
```

[image]